# How long does Netz last?

Tags: tefilla, zemanim, hanetz-sunrise

If one wants to daven Netz (at sunrise) how long of a period does one have to have caught this time? Is it only a few seconds, or longer?

Comment: Surely this depends on latitude/season

Answer (score 1):

The actual length of Netz is a little more than 2 minutes.

The MB in Biur Halacha 58:1 sv Kemo indicates that the time is at the beginning of Netz. (He also discusses the shita of the Rema who says Netz is about an hour, which he finds hard to explain based on facts. The Gr”a says it’s typo)

The [Ish Matzliach](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7535&st=&pgnum=170) in the middle of an extremely long Teshuva, (in the linked page, start at the bold words and go as long as you can) brings this time down, with all the different opinions if the time to start is at the beginning, in middle, or end of the Netz.

Practically speaking the [Pnenei Halacha](https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/02-11-06/#_te02ftnref11_6) says the custom is to try to catch the beginning of Netz but not to be too overly concerned since there are plenty of opinions that give more time.

Comment: it's definitely not a typo in the rama, see darkei moshe who cites and explicitly makes fun of the girsa the gra supports; you can try to disagree with the rama but you can't pretend that opinion wasn't alive and well 500 years ago.

Comment: the gra (and most people nowadays) think like modern astronomers so they don't understand how the rishonim's words fit with the metzius and hence are too quick to reject lots of traditional sources. it's like the rishonim were speaking a different language: of course it doesn't take an hour for the disk of the sun to come over the horizon, but that's obviously not what rishonim meant by 'sunrise'.

Comment: Regardless of the time that Rema mentioned, the M”A says, and the Machtzis Hashekel and Levushei Serad explain, that the time to daven would be at the beginning of Netz and according to the other opinions it might be at the end of Netz which is only a few minutes later. So for this question, about when to daven, the hour long mentioned by Rema is irrelevant since nobody says that davening an hour after sunrise is still Netz.

Comment: Depending which opinion you're holding like of what the goal of davening netz is. We have a machloket rishonim if it's tefilla or shema that's supposed to be at netz and furthermore a machloket of if the goal is to start right away or just to have the two things on the right two sides of that line. For the one girsa the rambam is giving the longer time for his view of shema being before netz, but for the other opinions you may indeed have much longer. (like consider https://mi.yodeya.com/a/118891/759 even if shema isn't before netz it could still be worth praying the amida during netz)

Comment: Anyway the rama isn't saying an hour after what you call sunrise is still netz. That's the whole point. Your two minutes are just somewhere in his hour.